# keep getting a spam voicemail but phone never rang

Tags: voicemail

i keep getting a spam voicemail but phone never rang and it is always the same spam message, i'm on t-mobile with a moto g 4th gen.

tried searching for apps with adware, nothing found
ran lookout antivirus, nothing found

Comment: Is your mobile rooted or unrooted.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably auto-sent to voicemail because either Moto or T-Mobile detects its spam. Nothing to worry about here, spam voicemails happen *all the time*. Consider blocking the number.